# Jquery.parseJSON compatibility on Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem with the following snip of code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "AjouterAttribut.php",
    data: { val: valvaleur, table: nomvaleur }
}).success(function(message)
{
    var rep = $.trim(message);
    if (rep == '-')
    {
        $.unblockUI();
        alert("Cet enregistrement existe déjà");
    } 
    else 
    {
        var Tableau = jQuery.parseJSON(rep);
        boutonappuye.prev().find('option').remove();

        boutonappuye.next().attr("disabled", "true");
        boutonappuye.next().find('img').attr('src', 'images/Supprimer_nonactif.png')

        for (var i=0; i< Tableau.length; i++)
        {
        boutonappuye.prev().append("<option value="+ Tableau[i][0] +">" + Tableau[i][1] + "</option>");
        }
        $.unblockUI();
    }
});
```

This line, specifically:

```
var Tableau = jQuery.parseJSON(rep);
```

This works on Firefox 12. However, I need to make it compatible on Firefox 3.6. Much to my dismay, the javascript just crashes there. I tried doing an alert of the contents of the rep variable right before that line. It gave this:

```
[["1","Etudiant"],["3","Etudiant privilege"],["2","Professeur"],["7","wrerew"]]
```

If I change the line of code above for:

```
var Tableau = jQuery.parseJSON('[["1","Etudiant"],["3","Etudiant privilege"],["2","Professeur"],["7","wrerew"]]');
```

It works. I'm not even sure why putting the variable in the function causes it to crash.

Thank you~

Comment: Tried to turn the rep into a string, didn't work, it leaves my Tableau variable empty after the parseJSON.

Comment: Trying putting the datatype of my ajax call to json, still no result.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 is officially dead since a few days. You shouldn't have to support it anymore!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the encoding, my php file was encoded in UTF-8 with BOM. Had to encode it without.